# Chrome Extension - multiple asynchrone XMLhttpRequests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

The idea is to start multiple xmlhttp requests in an loop and let them store their result in a global variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < something; i++) {
  fetch_site(url, i);
}
```

Now the function fetch_site() looks like this:

```
// the result will be palced at the i-th field in the "content"-array
function fetch_site(url, i) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

// Milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated
xmlhttp.timeout = 500;
xmlhttp.ontimeout = function () {
  content[i] = "none";
  console.log("ontimeout: content[" + i + "] is now set to " + content[i] );
};

// On error
xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
  content[i] = "none";
  console.log("onerror: content[" + i + "] is now set to " + content[i] );
};

// On success
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      content[i] = xmlhttp.responseText;
      // Deleting unneccessary spaces
      content[i] = content[i].trim();
    } else content[i] = "none";
  }
};

//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","Lookup/simple");
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I can confirm that each an every request gets send. However google-chrome marks them as pending and when diggin deeper it defines them as stalled.

By the way, this code is used in a chrome extension. Hence it might be a permission problem. Though I would not expect it to be one as I have granted my extension to fetch every site.
The corresponding manifest-file includes the following lines:

```
"permissions": [
  "storage",
  "http://*/",
  "https://*/"
],
```